# How to run popover for elements inside dataTables?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, popover

I  try to run bootstrap popover for some elements inside table that I run datatable on it.I use this code but dont worked.

JS:

```
$('#dynamic-table1').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [
        [3, "desc"]
    ],
    "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    }
});
```

html:

```
<a data-toggle="popover" title="توضیحات کاربر ارشد" data-content="Description" data-trigger="focus">
```

How solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define not working? My guess is you are confusing `focus` with `hover` :

```html
<a data-toggle="popover" title="توضیحات کاربر ارشد" data-content="Description" 
   data-trigger="hover">
popover
</a>
```

and then your code works -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ehnnm5kk/**

Answer (score 0):

you can use same but different syntax in bootstrap 5.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" 
    data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus"
    data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
    Click to toggle popover
 </button>
```